# How to convert character column contraining "0/0" to numeric

Tags: r

I have a data frame and all the columns are classified as a character. Each column contains a fraction. I want to convert the columns to integers but some of the columns have the fraction "0/0", which R doesn't seem to like. I tried the following but got

```
df2 <- as.numeric(df)
```

and get the following

```
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I haven't been able to find a post the explains how to convert a character containing a fraction of "0/0" to a numeric value of 0. I realize that there is a reason why R is giving me trouble with the whole divide by zero. I am just dealing with genetic data and it is much easier to convert the data to numeric and adding everything up than it is to do some kind of replacement function. The actual data frame is 10s of millions of rows and 500+ rows.

Here is an example data frame

```
df <- structure(list(`GEN[5].GT` = c("0/1", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", 
 "0/1", "0/0", "0/0", "1/1", "0/0", "0/0"), `GEN[1].GT` = c("0/0", 
 "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0"
 ), `GEN[6].GT` = c("1/1", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", 
 "0/1", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0"), `GEN[9].GT` = c("0/0", "0/0", 
 "0/0", "0/0", "0/1", "0/0", "0/0", "0/1", "0/0", "0/0"), `GEN[89].GT` = c("0/0", 
 "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0"
 ), `GEN[453].GT` = c("0/0", "0/0", "0/1", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", 
 "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0"), `GEN[554].GT` = c("0/0", "0/0", 
 "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "1/1", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0"), `GEN[9864].GT` = c("0/0", 
 "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0"
 ), `GEN[1234].GT` = c("1/1", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", 
 "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0"), `GEN[3333].GT` = c("0/0", "0/0", 
 "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "1/1", "0/0", "0/1", "0/0", "0/0")), row.names = c(NA, 
 10L), class = "data.frame")

# Expected output
 df2 <- structure(list(`GEN[5].GT` = c("0.5", "0", "0", "0", 
 "0.5", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0"), `GEN[1].GT` = c("0", 
 "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"
 ), `GEN[6].GT` = c("1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
 "0.5", "0", "0", "0"), `GEN[9].GT` = c("0", "0", 
 "0", "0", "0.5", "0", "0", "0.5", "0", "0"), `GEN[89].GT` = c("0", 
 "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"
 ), `GEN[453].GT` = c("0", "0", "0.5", "0", "0", "0", 
 "0", "0", "0", "0"), `GEN[554].GT` = c("0", "0", 
 "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0"), `GEN[9864].GT` = c("0", 
 "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"
 ), `GEN[1234].GT` = c("1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
 "0", "0", "0", "0"), `GEN[3333].GT` = c("0", "0", 
 "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0.5", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: added the expected output

Comment: Does your real data contain more fractions which need to be correctly evaluated, or will they all be 0, 0.5, or 1? If those are the only three options, might be best to just write them out in a `dplyr::case_when` rather than try to get R to parse/evaluate them

Comment: You say fractions but your expected output for `"0/1"` is `"0.5"`, which raises a couple questions. First: 0 divided by 1 is not 0.5, so perhaps this is a categorical thing and not mathematical division? Second: string of a decimal? I'd expect it to be numeric.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan for this particular dataset, they all will be either 0, 0.5, or 1

Comment: @r2evans it is more an of a categorical thing rather than traditional division. akrun seem to hit the nail on the head with this answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to capture the two sides and put them inside parentheses, replace `/` with `+`, and then divide by 2.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   #try mutate_all(~gsub('(.*)/(.*)','(\\1+\\2)/2',.)) to see the underlying formula 
   mutate_all(~eval(parse(text=gsub('(.*)/(.*)','(\\1+\\2)/2',.))))  %>% 
   ungroup()

# A tibble: 10 x 10
   `GEN[5].GT` `GEN[1].GT` `GEN[6].GT` `GEN[9].GT` `GEN[89].GT` `GEN[453].GT` `GEN[554].GT` `GEN[9864].GT` `GEN[1234].GT`
         <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
 1         0.5           0         1           0              0           0               0              0              1
 2         0             0         0           0              0           0               0              0              0
 3         0             0         0           0              0           0.5             0              0              0
 4         0             0         0           0              0           0               0              0              0
 5         0.5           0         0           0.5            0           0               0              0              0
 6         0             0         0           0              0           0               0              0              0
 7         0             0         0.5         0              0           0               1              0              0
 8         1             0         0           0.5            0           0               0              0              0
 9         0             0         0           0              0           0               0              0              0
10         0             0         0           0              0           0               0              0              0
# ... with 1 more variable: `GEN[3333].GT` <dbl>
```

Comment: Since you claim to have 10s of millions of rows, I would expect `eval(parse(...))` to perform poorly in the large scale. It might be useful to you to do some benchmarking between this and @akrun's answer.

Answer (score 2):

We can create a row names column (`rownames_to_column` from `tibble`), then split each column at the delimiter (`/`) with `separate_rows` while `convert`ing the type automatically, grouped by 'rn', get the `mean` of each of the columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
   separate_rows(-1, convert = TRUE) %>%
   group_by(rn) %>% 
   summarise_all(mean) %>%
   select(-rn)
# A tibble: 10 x 10
#   `GEN[5].GT` `GEN[1].GT` `GEN[6].GT` `GEN[9].GT` `GEN[89].GT` `GEN[453].GT` `GEN[554].GT` `GEN[9864].GT` `GEN[1234].GT` `GEN[3333].GT`
#         <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
# 1         0.5           0         1           0              0           0               0              0              1            0  
# 2         0             0         0           0              0           0               0              0              0            0  
# 3         0             0         0           0              0           0               0              0              0            0  
# 4         0             0         0           0              0           0.5             0              0              0            0  
# 5         0             0         0           0              0           0               0              0              0            0  
# 6         0.5           0         0           0.5            0           0               0              0              0            0  
# 7         0             0         0           0              0           0               0              0              0            1  
# 8         0             0         0.5         0              0           0               1              0              0            0  
# 9         1             0         0           0.5            0           0               0              0              0            0.5
#10         0             0         0           0              0           0               0              0              0            0
```

Or another option as @IceCreamToucan mentioned in the comments it to split the cells with `strsplit` and take the `mean`

```
library(purrr)    
df %>% 
   mutate_all(~ map_dbl(strsplit(., '/'), ~ mean(as.numeric(.))))
```

---

Or another option possibly more efficient (in `base R`) is to pass a named vector, replace the values by matching

```
nm1 <- setNames(c(0, 0.5, 0.5, 1), c("0/0", "1/0", "0/1", "1/1"))
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) nm1[x])
df
#   GEN[5].GT GEN[1].GT GEN[6].GT GEN[9].GT GEN[89].GT GEN[453].GT GEN[554].GT GEN[9864].GT GEN[1234].GT GEN[3333].GT
#1        0.5         0       1.0       0.0          0         0.0           0            0            1          0.0
#2        0.0         0       0.0       0.0          0         0.0           0            0            0          0.0
#3        0.0         0       0.0       0.0          0         0.5           0            0            0          0.0
#4        0.0         0       0.0       0.0          0         0.0           0            0            0          0.0
#5        0.5         0       0.0       0.5          0         0.0           0            0            0          0.0
#6        0.0         0       0.0       0.0          0         0.0           0            0            0          1.0
#7        0.0         0       0.5       0.0          0         0.0           1            0            0          0.0
#8        1.0         0       0.0       0.5          0         0.0           0            0            0          0.5
#9        0.0         0       0.0       0.0          0         0.0           0            0            0          0.0
#10       0.0         0       0.0       0.0          0         0.0           0            0            0          0.0
```

Comment: Nice idea to take the mean, could also do that without separate_rows/grouping: `df %>% 
  mutate_all(~ map_dbl(strsplit(., '/'), ~ mean(as.numeric(.))))`